# How are primitives passed into functions as arguments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When passing a primitive into a JavaScript function as an argument is a copy of the value being ( i.e. a new variable being created ) passed into the function or is it just a pointer to the variables location in memory like what happens with objects?  Since objects are mutable its easy to prove, however, since primitives are immutable they will always be reassigned so it's hard to tell whats is happening behind the scenes.

In the following code ( http://jsbin.com/egufog/2/edit ) demonstrates what I mean:

```
var pvalue = 'foo'; //primitive

var ovalue = { foo : 'foo' }; //object

changeMe( pvalue, ovalue ); //changes values

console.log( pvalue, ovalue ); //pvalue unchanged, ovalue was changed

reassignMe( ovalue ); //reassigns the object, breaking the reference

console.log( ovalue ); //ovalue remains unchanged

function changeMe( primitive, obj ){
  primitive = 'bar'; //did this reassign the pointer or just create another variable?

  obj.foo = 'bar'; //updates the object in memory
}

function reassignMe( obj ) {
  obj = { baz : 'baz' }; //reassignment breaks the pointer reference
}
```

Comment: I guess they're passed as value, because that would be coherent and more efficient but how does that implementation matters ? You say yourself you woudln't see any difference.

Comment: I guess that's an implementation detail.

Comment: What are you asking? I only ask this since in your question you said "it is easy to prove" and then proceeded to prove it to us right afterwards. Sorry for the repost, accidentally posted this as an answer.

Comment: I'm just trying to grok how things are happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I'm asking if a pointer to the memory location is being passed or if a copy of the actual value is being passed with primitives, its easy to prove with objects, but not primitives.

Comment: I think you have to clarify which "level of implementation" you are talking about. JavaScript is *pass/call by value* (or *pass/call by sharing* not *pass/call by reference*. Even though case of objects, the value is reference to the object, it's not the same as *pass/call by reference*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy.

Comment: I think what happens depends entirely on the implementation of the JS engine. Someone who knows the internals of one could probably answer this (or you could go look at the source for eg. V8).

Comment: What if you pass in a method of an object?  Here's a good article on the topic:  http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: @MStodd: Functions are objects too.

Comment: question: if primitives are passed by value, would that result in actually the double abount of memory that is being used? So would it be able to create a large string variable and work out the memory difference that would be to expect if that variable was passed by reference or passed by value? If so, then this could be a relatively simple test to find out what it is.

Comment: It's not an implementation detail. If it were, you couldn't expect simple JS to run the same way across devices. Primitives are passed by value (copy of the primitive data is passed) and objects are passed by reference (copy of the pointer to the object is passed).

Answer (score 3):

> When passing a primitive into a JavaScript function as an argument is a copy of the value being ( i.e. a new variable being created ) passed into the function or is it just a pointer to the variables location in memory like what happens with objects?

A function parameter always creates a new variable, i.e. a slot with a name that contains a value. As javascript has no pointers, it holds the location of the *value* not of the variable.

> Since primitives are immutable they will always be reassigned so it's hard to tell whats is happening behind the scenes.

Exactly, we don't know. But since they are immutable it does not make a difference whether the variable is assigned a copy of the value itself or the location of the value. The JS engine is free to choose that - I would expect the usage of references for large strings, but not for numbers or boolean values.

> ```
> changeMe( 'foo' )
> function changeMe( primitive, obj ){
>     primitive = 'bar'; //did this reassign the pointer or just create another variable?
> }
> ```

There's no new variable, `primitive` existed since you called the function. It previously held the value `'foo'` (or a pointer to it), and now does hold the value `'bar'` (or a pointer to it).

Only for objects we know that the variables holding them contain pointers to the data structure in memory - they are known as "*reference values*" (in contrast to the *primitive* ones). If you mutate the data, you can see that from every variable referencing the object.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that primitives are immutable. String primitives are, but number and boolean aren't.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Of course they are? Can you show an example how you would mutate them?

Comment: var x = 5;  ++x;  This does not cause a new space in memory to be created for 6.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You're assigning values to variables here. I have no idea what this has to with the immutability of numbers.

Comment: When talking about immutability, we are talking about the ability for the scripting engine to assign a new value to a variable using the same memory address that was already set aside. With strings, this is not possible because the memory has already been set aside and assigning a bigger string than was previously stored would mean that there is more data that can fit in the space allotted, and so, strings are immutable.  This is not the case for numbers and Booleans. A new memory address is not needed to change the value of a memory address from say, 5 to 500, thus numbers aren't immutable.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Immutability is about values, and has nothing to do with memory addresses. The ability to assign to variables makes the difference between constants and variables. The number in the variable is just as immutable as the pointer to the string is - if you change the variable (write to the memory), you store a different value (number, pointer, etc) than before instead of altering the existing one.

Comment: Well, I think we are ships passing in the night here. Of course the literal number 5 can never become any other literal than 5 and so yes, the actual value is immutable,  I see what you are describing now and you are correct in your point, but immutability certainly can (and does) also pertain to memory addresses to indicate whether that specific address can take on a new value or if it is locked into the value it has been assigned (as is the case with a string value).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too simple to say

`console.log( pvalue, ovalue ); //pvalue unchanged, ovalue was changed`

If we think of of pvalue and ovalue as references to objects, we save our references on the stack, make copies for the called function to use, then call the function.  At this point, the called function has it's own references, but it's still pointing to the same objects, and is therefore able to change them

If we reassign a reference passed into a function, such as

`primitive = 'bar'; //did this reassign the pointer or just create another variable?`
or
`obj = { baz : 'baz' }; //reassignment breaks the pointer reference`

Then all we did was change the copy of the original reference, the scope of which is limited to the called function.  One we get back to the calling function, we take the original reference off the stack

Answer (score 0):

From what I know when primitive types are passed in an argument of a function then they are passed by value and a copy of the primitive value is passed in the function. 
Which means that if within the function you change the value of the argument then the 'original' value of the variable is intact.

```
var pvalue = 'foo'; //primitive

function changeMe(prim) {
    prim = 'bar';
}
changeMe(pvalue);
console.log(pvalue); // pvalue remains foo (unchanged)
```

However if you try the same with an object it will change the 'original' object since it's new variable in the function will point also to the original object. But that doesn't mean that it was passed in by reference. Check this out.

```
function changeMe(obj) {
    obj.foo = "foo";
    obj = new Object();
    obj.foo = "bar";
}

var ovalue = { foo : null };
changeMe(ovalue);

alert(ovalue.foo); // Changed to foo but not to bar
```

This means that if the obj was passed in by refence then when I assigned the new Object to the obj and then changed the property that it would also change the original object's foo property to bar.

So how I think about it is that the object is passed in also by value and when you use that value to assign a property for example it will point it to the same object as before. However if you reassign within the function the obj to a new Object then this new Object will point to a different local Object that can be accessed just within the scope of the function it was created in.